# Draw Graph using Java 2D and Swing

Tags: java, swing, graph, java-2d

I want to know if it is easy to draw a graph (circle and arrows to link each circles) using 
Java2D and Swing. And I want some tutorials or just small examples.

Comment: Have a look at [this page in the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/).

Comment: I find it easy.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the API is quite easy to use, so it really depends on what you will be drawing...

See this website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you're doing. If you're only doing things like drawing a line from a point to another point using the click of a mouse, then it is quite simple. For something like that, all you would need to do is implement the

```
 public void drawComponent(Graphics g){
      g.drawLine(/*xPosition of click*/,/*yPosition of click*/, null);
 }
```

method inside your class, and then implement MouseListener for the mouse click. Just implement by doing

```
 import ...
 public class ClassName implements MouseListener
```

and then the mouse listener onto whatever component you're using such as a JFrame, JPanel, or anything such as those.

Hope that helps